# Pythonic way to sorting list of namedtuples by field name

Tags: python, sorting, namedtuple, field-names

I want to sort a list of named tuples without having to remember the index of the fieldname. My solution seems rather awkward and was hoping someone would have a more elegant solution.

```
from operator import itemgetter
from collections import namedtuple

Person = namedtuple('Person', 'name age score')
seq = [
    Person(name='nick', age=23, score=100),
    Person(name='bob', age=25, score=200),
]

# sort list by name
print(sorted(seq, key=itemgetter(Person._fields.index('name'))))
# sort list by age
print(sorted(seq, key=itemgetter(Person._fields.index('age'))))
```

Thanks,
Nick

Comment: Is the field name always given as a string or does the solution by @clyfish also work?

Comment: I wasn't trying to do anything dynamic, so both solutions work perfectly.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

```
from operator import attrgetter
from collections import namedtuple

Person = namedtuple('Person', 'name age score')
seq = [Person(name='nick', age=23, score=100),
       Person(name='bob', age=25, score=200)]
```

Sort list by name

```
sorted(seq, key=attrgetter('name'))
```

Sort list by age

```
sorted(seq, key=attrgetter('age'))
```

Answer (score 69):

```
sorted(seq, key=lambda x: x.name)
sorted(seq, key=lambda x: x.age)
```

Comment: I think this is more elegant than using `attrgetter`

Comment: I prefer the attrgetter, but that is just taste. An advantage is also if I were to get the fields to sort on dynamically. Then I could just pass the string.

Comment: @zenpoy Keep in mind `attrgetter` performs much better and `lambda`s arent usually considered elegant

Comment: and `sorted(seq, key=lambda x: [x.age, x.name])` sorts by multiple attributes

Answer (score 19):

I tested the two alternatives given here for speed, since @zenpoy was concerned about performance.

Testing script:

```
import random
from collections import namedtuple
from timeit import timeit
from operator import attrgetter

runs = 10000
size = 10000
random.seed = 42
Person = namedtuple('Person', 'name,age')
seq = [Person(str(random.randint(0, 10 ** 10)), random.randint(0, 100)) for _ in range(size)]

def attrgetter_test_name():
    return sorted(seq.copy(), key=attrgetter('name'))

def attrgetter_test_age():
    return sorted(seq.copy(), key=attrgetter('age'))

def lambda_test_name():
    return sorted(seq.copy(), key=lambda x: x.name)

def lambda_test_age():
    return sorted(seq.copy(), key=lambda x: x.age)

print('attrgetter_test_name', timeit(stmt=attrgetter_test_name, number=runs))
print('attrgetter_test_age', timeit(stmt=attrgetter_test_age, number=runs))
print('lambda_test_name', timeit(stmt=lambda_test_name, number=runs))
print('lambda_test_age', timeit(stmt=lambda_test_age, number=runs))
```

Results:

```
attrgetter_test_name 44.26793992166096
attrgetter_test_age 31.98247099677627
lambda_test_name 47.97959511074551
lambda_test_age 35.69356267603864
```

Using lambda was indeed slower. Up to 10% slower.

**EDIT**:

Further testing shows the results when sorting using multiple attributes. Added the following two test cases with the same setup:

```
def attrgetter_test_both():
    return sorted(seq.copy(), key=attrgetter('age', 'name'))

def lambda_test_both():
    return sorted(seq.copy(), key=lambda x: (x.age, x.name))

print('attrgetter_test_both', timeit(stmt=attrgetter_test_both, number=runs))
print('lambda_test_both', timeit(stmt=lambda_test_both, number=runs))
```

Results:

```
attrgetter_test_both 92.80101586919373
lambda_test_both 96.85089983147456
```

Lambda still underperforms, but less so. Now about 5% slower.

Testing is done on Python 3.6.0.

Comment: Thanks for the multi attribute sort case :)

Answer (score 4):

since nobody mentioned using itemgetter(), here how you do using itemgetter().

```
from operator import itemgetter
from collections import namedtuple

Person = namedtuple('Person', 'name age score')
seq = [
    Person(name='nick', age=23, score=100),
    Person(name='bob', age=25, score=200),
]

# sort list by name
print(sorted(seq, key=itemgetter(0)))

# sort list by age
print(sorted(seq, key=itemgetter(1)))
```

Answer (score 4):

This might be a bit too 'magical' for some, but I'm partial to:

```
# sort list by name
print(sorted(seq, key=Person.name.fget))
```

Edit: this assumes `namedtuple` uses the `property()` built-in to implement the accessors, because it leverages the `fget` attribute on such a property ([see documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property)). This may still be true in some implementations but it seems CPython no longer does that, which I think is related to optimization work referenced in https://bugs.python.org/issue32492 (so, since 3.8). Such fragility is the cost of the "magic" I mentioned; `namedtuple` certainly doesn't promise to use `property()`.

Writing `Person.name.__get__` is better (works before & after the implementation change) but is maybe not worth the arcaneness vs. just writing it more plainly as `lambda p: p.name`

Comment: Could you please add some context to your answer? I tried it but am getting *AttributeError: '_collections._tuplegetter' object has no attribute 'fget'*.

Comment: Sure. This approach used to work but it depended on a particular implementation detail of namedtuple. That seems to have been changed in https://bugs.python.org/issue32492. Will add an edit to the answer shortly.