# Python Namedtuple Indexing Instance

Tags: python, namedtuple

So Here is my code for my lab coding project that I am currently working on:

```
from collections import namedtuple
Restaurant = namedtuple('Restaurant', 'name cuisine phone dish price')

# Restaurant attributes: name, kind of food served, phone number, best dish, price of that dish

RC = [Restaurant("Thai Dishes", "Thai", "334-4433", "Mee Krob", 12.50), 
      Restaurant("Nobu", "Japanese", "335-4433", "Natto Temaki", 5.50), 
      Restaurant("Nonna", "Italian", "355-4433", "Stracotto", 25.50), 
      Restaurant("Jitlada", "Thai", "324-4433", "Paht Woon Sen", 15.50), 
      Restaurant("Nola", "New Orleans", "336-4433", "Jambalaya", 5.50), 
      Restaurant("Noma", "Modern Danish", "337-4433", "Birch Sap", 35.50), 
      Restaurant("Addis Ababa", "Ethiopian", "337-4453", "Yesiga Tibs", 10.50)]
```

My question to you as a beginner is: what method(s) should I use to allow my program to index specific parts of the list?

For example, how do I go about indexing a list of all of the restaurants from the greater list? This list includes just the restaurants from the list not all the other information like the phone numbers, etc...

I have used both slice methods and list functions in attempt to figure this out myself and it did not prove to work. >:(

Comment: I guess I'm not sure what you mean by index in this circumstance?

Comment: This is the specific question that lab poses if this helps:

Comment: Assuming you mean the `name` by "all of the restaurants",  `RC[0].name` would be the first entry.

Comment: You already have a list of restaurants.  Each restaurant has various bits of data associated with it.  Are you asking how to get a list of the *names* of the restaurants?

Comment: "The list of restaurants, arranged alphabetically by restaurant name."

Comment: Oh, so what you actually need is to SORT based on an attribute. There are plenty of existing answers on that topic

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12087905/pythonic-way-to-sorting-list-of-namedtuples-by-field-name

Comment: @Colleen I already saw that topic before I posted this. That particular example that was given as a solution did not work for me.

Comment: Then your question needs to address how it didn't work for you.

Comment: thank you Moshe and @elb0w for helping out!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure when you say index if you just want the values or for performance. But for basic retrieval you could just do something like this

```
[r.name for r in RC]
```

Which would give you all the names of restaurants you have in RC

You could get fancier,

```
RC = [...]
def getValues(name):
   return [getattr(r, name) for r in RC]
```

Then you can just do,

```
getValues('name')
```

If you need it to cache you can look into using memoize

Answer (score 0):

Not completely sure what you mean by "index", but this might do what you want:

```
from collections import namedtuple
Restaurant = namedtuple('Restaurant', 'name cuisine phone dish price')

# Restaurant attributes: name, kind of food served, phone number, best dish, price of that dish

RC = [Restaurant("Thai Dishes", "Thai", "334-4433", "Mee Krob", 12.50),
      Restaurant("Nobu", "Japanese", "335-4433", "Natto Temaki", 5.50),
      Restaurant("Nonna", "Italian", "355-4433", "Stracotto", 25.50),
      Restaurant("Jitlada", "Thai", "324-4433", "Paht Woon Sen", 15.50),
      Restaurant("Nola", "New Orleans", "336-4433", "Jambalaya", 5.50),
      Restaurant("Noma", "Modern Danish", "337-4433", "Birch Sap", 35.50),
      Restaurant("Addis Ababa", "Ethiopian", "337-4453", "Yesiga Tibs", 10.50)]

def retrieve(records, column):
    """ return list of values for column from a list of namedtuples """
    if records and column not in records[0]._fields:
        raise ValueError('invalid column name:' + repr(column))
    return [getattr(rec, column) for rec in records]

print retrieve(RC, 'name')
```

Output:

```
['Thai Dishes', 'Nobu', 'Nonna', 'Jitlada', 'Nola', 'Noma', 'Addis Ababa']
```