# how to 'index' a named tuple

Tags: python, namedtuple

I have a namedtuple, that contains several namedtuples within it.

Each of the inner tuples essentially has a unique 'id', along with other useful information. 
I know the ID of the tuple I want to access, and Im wondering if there's an easy way to 'index' the namedtuple to extract the exact element I want without doing something like:

```
for inner_tuple in outer_tuple:
    if inner_tuple.id == desired_id:
        found tuple = inner_tuple
        break
```

Comment: It sounds like you want to store them in a dictionary. Set the key as the id.

Comment: If you could sort the outer tuple, you could do a binary search. You could also easily build a separate dictionary that mapped each id directly to its index in the outer tuple. Otherwise you'll need to completely replace the outer tuple with another data structure, like a dictionary.

Comment: Also related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/12087905/1736679

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a generator expression with `next()` to find the first match, or `None` if nothing matched. This still requires a loop:

```
found = next((tup for tup in outer_tuple if tup.id == desired_id), None)
```

The alternative is to use a dictionary keyed on `id` instead.