# How would I sort an outputted text file by the nth column - Python

Tags: python

My code:

```
infile = open("ALE.txt", "r")
outfile = open("ALE_sorted.txt", "w")

for line in infile:
    data = line.strip().split(',')
    wins = int(data[2])
    percentage = 162 / wins
    p = str(data[0]) + ", " + data[1] + ", " + data[2] + ", " + 
str(round(percentage, 3)) + "\n"
    outfile.write(p)
infile.close()
outfile.close()
```

The original infile("ALE.txt") is just the first three columns below. The text file that is output from the code above looks like this:

Baltimore, 93, 69, 2.348
Boston, 69, 93, 1.742
New York, 95, 67, 2.418
Tampa Bay, 90, 72, 2.25
Toronto, 73, 89, 1.82

I know the code correctly calculates the win percentage (column 2/total wins), but I would like to sort this list by the 4th column (win percentage).

Comment: why not place it in a list, and sort ?

Comment: You might find this a lot simpler if you use pandas or at least, the `csv` module. Also `eval`?

Comment: @S.R. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: @pvg changed eval to int. Didn't think it mattered - got same result

Comment: Create a tuple and sort it based on the forth column. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12087905/pythonic-way-to-sorting-list-of-namedtuples-by-field-name

Comment: @S.R. I've tried adding the line sorted(p, key=lambda x: x.percentage)

but to no avail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append your data to a list, say `d`.

Sort it with the third item(4th column) of the list. Reference - [operator.itemgetter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter)

Write the sorted data to your output file.

**Contents of input file**

```
[kiran@localhost ~]$ cat infile.txt
Baltimore, 93, 69
Boston, 69, 93
New York, 95, 67
Tampa Bay, 90, 72
Toronto, 73, 89
```

**Code::**

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> d=[]
>>> with open('infile.txt','r') as infile:
...     for line in infile.readlines():
...             data = line.strip().split(',')
...             wins = int(data[2])
...             percentage = 162 / float(wins)
...             data.append(str(round(percentage, 3))) #add percentage to your list that already contains the name and two scores.
...             d.append(data) # add the line to a list `d`
...
>>> print d
[['Baltimore', ' 93', ' 69', '2.348'], ['Boston', ' 69', ' 93', '1.742'], ['New York', ' 95', ' 67', '2.418'], ['Tampa Bay', ' 90', ' 72', '2.25'], ['Toronto', ' 73', ' 89', '1.82']]
>>> d.sort(key=itemgetter(3)) #sort the list `d` with the third item(4th column) of your sublist.
>>> print d
[['Boston', ' 69', ' 93', '1.742'], ['Toronto', ' 73', ' 89', '1.82'], ['Tampa Bay', ' 90', ' 72', '2.25'], ['Baltimore', ' 93', ' 69', '2.348'], ['New York', ' 95', ' 67', '2.418']]
>>> #write the items in list d to your output file
>>>
>>> with open('outfile.txt','w') as outfile:
...     for line in d:
...             outfile.write(','.join(line)+'\n')
...
>>>
```

**Content of output file:**

```
[kiran@localhost ~]$ cat outfile.txt
Boston, 69, 93,1.742
Toronto, 73, 89,1.82
Tampa Bay, 90, 72,2.25
Baltimore, 93, 69,2.348
New York, 95, 67,2.418
```

Comment: This is the best answer. Thank you.

I had to change your line where you sorted the list because I was getting "itemgetter is not defined" to "d.sort(key=lambda x: x[3], reverse=True)", but it works and it's not a little easier to understand.

Comment: Glad to have helped. Sorry, I forgot to add the import statement. `from operator import itemgetter` should get you through the error.

Comment: I've added comments for your reference. Let me know if you need further explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
infile  = open("ALE.txt", "r")
outfile = open("ALE_sorted.txt", "w")

master_data = []

# Load in data from the infile and calculate the win percentage.
for line in infile:

    data = line.strip().split(', ')

    wins = int(data[2])
    percentage = 162 / wins
    data.append(str(round(percentage, 3)))

    master_data.append(data)

# Sort by the last column in reverse order by value and store the 
# sorted values and original indices in a list of tuples.
sorted_column = sorted([(float(data[-1]), index) for index, data in \
                        enumerate(master_data)], reverse = True)

# Reassign master_data according to the sorted positions.
master_data   = [master_data[data[1]] for data in sorted_column]

# Write each line to the outfile.
for data in master_data:

    outfile.write(str(", ".join(data) + "\n"))

infile.close()
outfile.close()
```

Where the contents of `infile` are the following:

```
Baltimore, 93, 69
Boston, 69, 93
New York, 95, 67
Tampa Bay, 90, 72
Toronto, 73, 89
```

The resultant `outfile` contains the following sorted by the values of the newly generated fourth column from highest to lowest:

```
New York, 95, 67, 2.418
Baltimore, 93, 69, 2.348
Tampa Bay, 90, 72, 2.25
Toronto, 73, 89, 1.82
Boston, 69, 93, 1.742
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that the infile("ALE.txt") is just the first 3 columns shown above. The one show is the intended format, just not sorted correctly. 

Is there a way to simply sort by the 4th column without changing my code too much?

Comment: I just edited the post. Let me know if the changes better reflect what you were going for.

Comment: Why not use CsvWriter instead of joining a list on commas anyway?

Comment: @cricket_007 That would definitely be more flexible, but was trying to work within the given format.

Answer (score 0):

First, when handling this, it is preferable to use line.split(',').strip().

```
import csv
with open('ALE.txt', 'r') as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    data = []
    for line in reader:
        formatted_line = [i.strip() for i in line]
        wins = int(formatted_line[2])
        percentage = 100*wins/total_wins
        formatted_line.append(str(round(percentage,3)))
        data.append(formatted_line)
    data = sorted(p, lambda x: x[3])
with open('ALE_sorted.txt', 'w', newline='') as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    writer.writerows(data)
```

Comment: I just get the error "total wins" is not defined when trying to use this code

Comment: @Choco Well, looking at the variables, can't you see that `wins` probably is the correct name?

Comment: Yes, that would be the correct variable, hence my confusion as to why you would write total_wins

Comment: @ChocolateGoosePoosey I don't understand why you use 162/wins to get percentage. I simply included the wins/total_wins * 100 to get you to check your calculations.

Comment: total_wins is still not defined. Sorry, I don't follow

Comment: @ChocolateGoosePoosey To clarify, I meant the total number of games played. I apologize if that was unclear. What I meant was that wouldn't win percentage be 93/162*100.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to sort the 4th column is to open your file using pandas.
Here's how to do it:

```
import pandas as pd

outfile=pd.read_csv("ALE_sorted.txt")
column=outfile.columns.values.tolist()  # will give you the name of your column

#It will return [0L,1L,2L,3L] where 3L is your fourth column and refers to a long int.

outfile.sort_values(by=[3L])

print(outfile.3L)  # to see the sorted column
```

This will yield:

```
3L
1.742
1.82
2.25
2.348
2.418
```